# Retrieving Outlook Attachments in VBA from sent mail

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

What I am trying to get done is to have it so that on a few E-Mail templates we have at my job, when we drag and drop a certain Excel file to it, it will select and copy a range of that Excel file into the body of the email. My only question, as I've looked everywhere and all the code I've found seems to be for emails that are being received, not written, is how do I access:

1. The attachments in an email that I am writing
2. The body of the E-Mail I am writing

I'm sure I can get the code for everything else I want once I can get the attachments for the current Email.

Before any mentions "just record the macro and see how outlook does it" for some reason my outlook does not have a "record macro" item anywhere, as that was my first go-to as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I access: The attachments in an email that I am writing The
>   body of the E-Mail I am writing

Here is a very basic example. I have not done any error handling but I am sure you can take care of it.

Let's say the email that you are writing looks like this

[image]

All you need is this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector

    '~~> Get the current open item
    Set NewMail = oInspector.CurrentItem

    With NewMail
        Debug.Print .To
        Debug.Print .subject
        Debug.Print .Body

        AttchCount = .Attachments.Count

        If AttchCount > 0 Then
            For I = 1 To AttchCount
                '~~> Print Attachment names
                Debug.Print .Attachments.Item(I).DisplayName
            Next I
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thank you. I was trying to go through the heirarchy and was having no luck.

Comment: Glad it worked. Btw the code run from VBA Outlook. In case you want it to run from VBA Excel then you will have to declare and create Outlook objects accordingly.

Comment: Now my big issue is trying to figure out what in the hell the event that gets fired when a new attachment is added. Still haven't figure out the naming scheme.

Comment: Well, that is just rude. Damn you Microsoft!

Comment: Whoa! Why blame MS for this? We should rather be thankful that they have given us such an important App. You can not only send and receive emails but you can do plethora of things with it ;)

Comment: I suppose so, just seems like that would be an event that should be there, you know?

Comment: I found that been working on it, but ran into some other problems. Trying to work through them before I ask another question. I'm attaching a file from a networked computer, and for some reason the PathName property of the attachment isn't set, so when I try to open "test1.xls" it gives me an error of "this file doesn't exist,..." I would just like to know how to get that event to fire for the current mail item; seems like it is almost impossible. Well, that and the examples don't work anyway. Even when all I change the text to is `MsgBox "Added`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Could I use something similar to scan a range of cells in excel (with email address) and verify that something was sent to each address on a given day?