# Getting contents of Outlook email attachment from networked computer

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I had needed to get the attachments from an email draft so that I could check if they were an Excel file, and if so read through the file to copy/paste a range of certain text into the body of the email.
Thanks to an answer from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553385/retreiving-outlook-attachments-in-vba-from-sent-mail) I've figured out how to get the email attachments.

I'm working on how to get when an attachment is added to that specific email draft, but the more pressing issue is that once I've added something, how do I open it in Excel?

```vb
Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector
Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
Dim eAttachment As Object
'~~> Get the current open item
Set NewMail = oInspector.CurrentItem

Set eAttachment = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With eAttachment
    ' Change file name to suit
    .Workbooks.Open FileName:=NewMail.Attachments.Item(1).FileName 
End With
```

This tells me that the file doesn't exist. So I look at the pathName on the attachment and find that it is set to nothing. There is no text there.

I'm thinking this has something to do with the Excel file being attached is on a computer networked to the one I am using.

I've searched, but "get contents of outlook email attachment on networked computer" didn't net me the results I wanted.

How would I gain access to the workbooks of the attached Excel file? Please note my example only uses the first attachment because for testing I am only attaching the one Excel file. When I can get the Excel file to open I will check the attachments to ensure they are excel files before I open them.

Edit: I just copied the file over to my local hard drive and tried to open the file, same issue. Am I going to have to open the file temporarily to open it? Is that what Outlook does when you edit an email attachment?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same issue I did - Here's what I've come to the conclusion of:

the PathName object, perhaps it is just the version of outlook that I am using, but it stores absolutely nothing. I tested it out on both of the computers in my office and my one at home, with the same result: it is just not there. Each Attachment object will have a SaveAsFile method that you can use to save the file to the temporary folder and access it from there via the usual Excel applications. This seems to be the only way, unfortunately, to read through the contents of a file attachment, even when it is simply a draft copy you are writing.

Also, what got me was the fact that I was trying, in the Excel file, to find the last cell in use, and was using the .End(xlUp) method. Remember, if you are using constants defined in the program you use, it is not defined in another. E.G. I was opening this Excel file from Outlook, technically, so trying to use xlUp gave me errors. Simply open up Excel, Word, or what have you to check the value of such constants and set them in your program.